# Possible faulty Schrader valve

Tags: schrader

I have a Schrader valve that is leaking air. I have a feeling that I over inflated the tyre. Recommended was 40-65psi and gaugue was showing just over 60. Up until that point it was pumping fine and then air started escaping and now leaks as much air as it takes in.

Any ideas what the problem might be or what issue I might have caused by over inflating, if I have?

Comment: If you put your finger tightly over the valve end does the leak stop.  It's possible that you've punctured the tube (due, eg, to a missing/defective rim strip).

Comment: Over pressure is not the problem, Schrader valves are good for hundreds of PSI (thousands for high spec ones).

Comment: If it is not leaking from the valve, check that the valve stem is not damaged. The valve stem may be damaged if the stem is crooked coming out of rim. This can occur, usually on a rear wheel when it has been ridden with low tire inflation.

Comment: it sounds like you're saying that it's leaking while you're pumping? In that case, check that the pump is securely attached to the valve stem. If it is, the problem isn't with the valve, and as Daniel R Hicks commented, you've punctured the tube somewhere else. Could be that the tube was pinched between the tire bead and rim or that a sharp object was in the tire and the inflated tube pressed hard against it or many other possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, when a Schrader valve starts leaking suddenly, the most common reason is that there is a small piece of debris that prevents the valve from closing. The easiest way to remove them is to slightly overinflate the tire, then fully open the valve by pressing the center pin. If this does not help, the valve might be faulty and the tube should be replaced.

Comment: With most schraders, you can unscrew the valve, inspect it, clean it, and/or replace it.

Comment: Schrader valve cores can be bought in service stations, at car parts dealers or bike stores as can be small tools to unscrew the core. (BTW the valve may also leak because the core isn't screwed-in tight enough.)

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure the valve is screwed in all the way. I put sealant in a tube for my son's bike, and the inner portion of the valve need to be torqued down. Fixed the problem. Also, it's not a bad idea to carry a valve tool with you on rides! Luckily I got to do this work at home in the garage. Would have been a real buzzkill out on the trail.

Comment: In my case, the leakage happened right after I filled in sealant to the tube... If you are also in this case, spin your wheel to let sealant apply evenly on your tube and clean up the core of your valve with water might help.